# I ran a .bat file that was connected to a .jar file. Now every time I turn on my computer the .jar runs and I don't want it to

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, jar

So recently I downloaded these 2 files for minecraft. http://rghost.net/49616042 is the link.  One of them is a .bat file and the other is a .jar file, and the .bat opens the .jar when you run it.  I ran the .bat and it did nothing, so I just deleted the files.  Although I have deleted them, every time i run my computer, whenever I log in i get this message. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dttnl.png that is the link to the image.  I do not want this to pop up whenever I log in and it gets very annoying.  I do not know how to get rid of it.  If anybody could help me get rid of it I would be very grateful.  Even though I deleted the files the script for the .bat was something like " java -jar ForceOP.jar " and that is all I remember of it.  I am currently running Windows 7 Home Premium.  64 bit operating system.  If anybody knows how to help please tell me!  Thank you!

Comment: It's running on startup?

Comment: This is not the right place to be asking this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow these instructions:

1.) Start menu
2.) Enter `msconfig`, press enter
3.) Go to the startup tab

Is anything unusual showing up that may be related to the keyword Java?

Also make sure this file doesn't contain the batch file:
Location: `Start Menu << All Programs << Startup`

Comment: Yes, thank you so much, i found a Java startup item and the file led directly to ForceOP.jar.  I think you have solved my problem, I just need to restart and find out.  There is also another java file that leads to java update, this one should be ok, correct?  Again, thank you so much for the help :)

Comment: Don't touch the one pertaining to the auto updater. Could someone explain the downvote please?

Comment: @user2921895 If the issue is solved would you mind accepting the answer =D

Comment: I accepted the answer now I'm sorry I was restarting my computer.  I don't know about the downvote that wasn't me I just made my account.

Comment: @JackRsps13 Ah, understood. I'm glad we could fix your issue. Just wanted to make note that questions unrelated to programming content shouldn't be posted here. I recommend asking questions like this on other websites such as [tomshardware](http://www.tomshardware.com).

Comment: Regarding downvote: see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194963 .